# st: Redraw content on geometry change

Tags: linux, suckless-terminal

I'm using st as my terminal and it's great. Just the right balance of minimalism and features. However, one thing that annoys me is the fact that whenever I change the geometry of my terminal window (by resizing or changing the font size) the content on the terminal session that goes out of bounds doesn't redraw or wrap around in any way, it just disappears (even when changing the geometry back to it's original size).

Does a patch exist which would solve this issue?

Thanks.